# Validating combination of columns not on the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are 4 tables present: **Course**, **Section**, **Enrollment**, **Student**.

- A Course has_many Sections
- Sections and Students share a many_to_many relationship where Enrollment is the join table

I am trying to add a validation in Enrollment so that a student can't be enrolled into multiple Sections of the same Course. I can't figure out how to implement this validation because Course is not immediately related to Enrollment.

Here are the models for further clarification:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course

  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :students, through :enrollments
end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :noDuplicateCourses

  def noDuplicateCourses
    if #TRYING TO FIGURE OUT HOW TO EXPRESS THE LOGIC HERE
      errors.add(:student_id, 'Already enrolled in a different section of this course')
    end
  end

  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :sections, through :enrollments
end
```

Comment: It’s pretty simple if you just write your own validation. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the `course_id` on `Enrollment`. This method is called **de-normalization**, meaning that you have duplicate content which you try to avoid in relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Just put your logic in place of `your_logic_here`.

```
validate :multiple_enrollment

private
# Custom validator
def multiple_enrollment
  if your_logic_here
    errors.add(self.class.table_name, "Student is already enrolled in another section of this course.")
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe I know the general logic, but I don't know how to express it syntactically here. 
Before adding an **ENROLLMENT** which is a combination of student_id and section_id, go to the **SECTION** table and find the row with the given section_id. Note the course_id present in this row and make sure non of the existing enrollments for the student link to this course_id. 
Would this necessitate a loop or can I do something similar to `if Section.where(:course_id => self.course_id, :student_id => self.student_id).present?` to check if such a link between student and course is already present?